# Where condition based on count of results

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm loading zones based on the request of a controller. A zone can be found via path or via a domain. For example, `https://example.com/zone123` could return two zones, one where the domain `example.com` is configured and another where the path `zone123` is configured:

```
zones = Zone.where("path = ? OR domain = ?", request.path, request.server_name)
```

A zone also has a `#public` flag. When I only find one zone (either by domain or path) I don't care about this public flag. But when I find two zones, I want to make sure that at least one of them has the `#public` flag set to `true`.

I could easily achieve this in ruby by doing

```
if zones.count > 1 && zones.any?(&:public?)
  # do stuff
end
```

However, **is there a way to achieve this within a single query in MySQL?** I guess I have to use a subquery, but I'm not sure how to add another condition based on the number of results returned from a previous select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the RoR syntax, but the SQL syntax for this would use an `EXISTS` test with `HAVING` in the subquery.

```
SELECT columns
FROM Zone
WHERE path = ? OR domain = ?
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Zone
    WHERE path = ? OR domain = ?
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 OR MAX(public) = 1
)
```